# Ajuda com GIT recuperação

Tags: linux, git, github

Pessoal eu tinha realizado um backup do meu dir `/.git/` e zipei.

Porém tive problemas nesse arquivo , consegui descompactar porém com erros. Gostaria de saber se tem um comando para realizar um `FORCE` para ele tentar recuperar o que for possível de arquivos desse `/.git/`

Comment: Qual o erro de saida?

Comment: E por que você não pode simplesmente clonar o rep de novo pra gerar essa pasta?

Comment: Não faz mais sentido você dar um `git pull`?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, faz uma pasta para cria de novo um depósito:

```
mkdir repo
mv .git repo
cd repo
```

Depois, apague vazios arquivos (coruptos)

```
find .git -size 0 -delete
```

Tenta uma verificação do sistema de arquivo:

```
git fsck
```

Se você tem um outro depósito, utiliza-lo para reconstruir o que falta:

```
git remote add origin url
git fetch origin
```